# What is the right combination of expected exceptions in my test case?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, junit4

While doing some data sources testing I wrote this small EJB.

```
@Stateless
@Remote(IEmpService.class)
@LocalBean
public class EmpService implements IEmpService {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public void removeAllEmps() {
    em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Emp").executeUpdate();
  }

  public List<Emp> getAllEmps() {
    return em.createQuery("FROM Emp", Emp.class).getResultList();
  }
}
```

As you can see there's one method to delete entries and one to select it. For my testing I created a user which has `select, insert, update` but no `delete` priviledges on the table. So executing the method `getAllEmps` will retrieve a result, while `removeAllEmps` should fail because of insufficient rights.

I wrote this test class

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class DataSourceTest {

  @Deployment
  public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    // ...
  }

  @EJB
  EmpService testclass;

  @Rule
  public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

  @UsingDataSet("empBefore.xml")
  @Test
  public void testGetAllEmps() {
    List<Emp> allEmps = testclass.getAllEmps();

    Assert.assertEquals(2, allEmps.size());
  }

  @UsingDataSet("empBefore.xml")
  @Test
  public void testDeleteAllEmps() {
    thrown.expect(EJBException.class);
    thrown.expectCause(CoreMatchers.isA(SQLSyntaxErrorException.class));
    
    testclass.removeAllEmps();
  }

}
```

While the `testGetAllEmps` test works smooths, I can't get the `testDeleteAllEmps` to produce a green bar as I don't get the right combination of "outer" (`thrown.excpect`) exception and "inner" (`thrown.expectCause`) exception. When executing the test method I get the following stack trace:

> javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
>
> [...]
>
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
>
> [...]
>
> ... 187 more
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
>
> [...]
>
> ... 217 more
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
>
> [...]
>
> ... 226 more

So my expectation is, that the "outer" exception is an `EJBTransaction` (as `EJBTransactionRolledbackException` is a child of it) and the "inner"  one is an `SQLSyntaxErrorException`.
But even when I change the `thrown.expect` to `EJBTransactionRolledbackException` and/or the `thrown.expectCause` to `SQLGrammarException` the test still doesn't get green.

Can anybody help me to identify the correct combination of exceptions I have to expect to get my test case run a green bar? (And maybe even retrieve the exception message?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the first exception was an SQLSyntaxErrorException, which caused an SQLGrammarException, which caused a PersistenceException, which caused an EJBTransactionRolledBackException.  So you could try

```
thrown.expect(EJBException.class);
thrown.expectCause(CoreMatchers.isA(PersistenceException.class));
```

or even

```
thrown.expect(EJBTransactionRolledBackException.class);
thrown.expectCause(CoreMatchers.isA(PersistenceException.class));
```

but why bother?  Isn't it enough just to expect an `EJBException`, and not be concerned about what the cause is?

Comment: Using a `PersistenceException` works to get a green bar. I concern about the cause, because in a test case I want to know that the method fails because of the correct cause to fail and not because of something else. And especially `EJBException` can mean nearly everything. I'm not quite happy with the using of `PersistenceException` without getting the message, but well...

Comment: You can write your own Hamcrest matcher on the `PersistenceException` if you want to prove more about it.